# Fatal error moving Opencart2 from live server to local machine

Tags: php, opencart

I have problem when I try to migrating my website live server to localhost has error

> Fatal error:
>
> require_once(): Failed opening required '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/startup.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecompusell\index.php on line 17

Below is my config.php

```
<?php
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/ecompusell/');

define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/ecompusell/');
// DIR
define('ROOT_APPLICATION','/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/catalog/');
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/');
define ('BASE_URI', '/C:xampp/htdocs/');
define('ROOT_URL', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/');
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/catalog/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD','/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/storage/logs/');define('DIR_MODIFICATION','/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/storage/modification/');define('DIR_store','/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/storage/');define('TEMPLATE_PATH','/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/catalog/view/theme/default/';
```

Comment: error resolved but banner,product images ,account not display.

Comment: Clear up title, slight wording changes and code indentation

Comment: Can you rename `/C:/xampp/htdocs/` to `http://localhost/` that will fix the issue